# Controller action with different URI doesn't work

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-boot-2

I have a problem with href of link tag used in my view model like `<link th:href="@{css/todo/index}" rel="stylesheet" />`.
This work nice on a controller action like `example.test/todos` but doesn't work when I try with a same action that just have a different URI like `example.test/todo/create`.

The problem is I don't have right links href to static files (css ; images ; and js). In the first action URI is `example.test/css/todo/index.css` but is `example.test/todo/css/todo/create.css` on the second action.

How to fix this ?
I using spring 2.2 and thymeleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally fix my problem by rewriting all links with a `/` first